# Thermal Runaway E1 Error, Extruder text jumps randomly

Tags: creality-ender-3, extruder, temperature, thermal-runaway

Ender 3 Pro, everything is stock except that I swapped the magnetic sheet for a glass bed.

As the tin says, I'll get this error around a half hour into a print:

```
THERMAL RUNAWAY: E1
PRINTER HALTED
Please Reset
```

I recorded it in the act, and here's some info I've collected:

The Extruder temp isn't consistent. It's set to 200 °C (Cura default), but will often wander around in the 197 °C-202 °C range.

There are random severe spikes where it will instantly go from 200 °C to 190 °C, then climb up to 205 °C.

About 5 minutes before error, it instantly dropped from 200 °C to 170 °C, then 180 °C, then 190 °C, then chilbed back up to 200 °C.

The error popped in when the extruder was at 190 °C.

See, it seems to jump around in an odd pattern, not just smoothly transitioning to a lower temperature. This leads me to suspect it's a sensor issue.

*However*, around the time these jumps were occurring, the plastic wouldn't adhere to the plate correctly. Some parts wouldn't stick:

[image: Photo of the first few layers of a printed model with edges curling up]

Compare the bottom (printed first) to the top (printed last). A lot of edges are popping up (although the bottom isn't perfect either).

This wasn't an issue until I moved my printer to the basement (from my bedroom) for a 30-hour print. I had it running for ~14 hours straight before my first encounter with this error. The temperate difference between my room and the basement is minimal.

I also leveled the bed before re-trying, which didn't solve the issue.

I am new to this, I got the printer 3 weeks ago. Extensive googling has resulted in many different solutions, but none specific to my printer's temperature situation. I post this hoping to find clarification for myself and provide a concise description of the problem so others down the line can find the solution easier.

Comment: Is it the same filament.

Comment: @Kilisi yup, nothing changed

Comment: I'd try another filament, it might have gone bad. I've had lots of filament issues with my ender 3 pro, but no mechanical/electrical ones yet

Comment: @Kilisi hmm.. I'll give that a shot

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is due to a wiring issue to the thermistor (or, less likely, thermistor itself may be damaged).  Check the integrity of your wires everywhere, especially at the thermistor end (easily damaged when cleaning hotends, changing nozzles, etc.).

An insulating silicone "sock" wouldn't hurt either against real temperature fluctuations, but these seem like phantom, electrically-based fluctuations.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was switching the voltage switch on the back of the printer from 230 volt to 115.  I had missed the step during the build to switch to my power outlet's voltage.